# SQL Server query showing most recent distinct data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to build a SQL query to recover only the most young record of a table (it has a Timestamp column already) where the item by which I want to filter appears several times, as shown in my table example:

[image: table example].

Basically, I have a `table1` with Id, Millis, fkName and Price, and a `table2` with Id and Name.

In `table1`, items can appear several times with the same fkName.

What I need to achieve is building up a single query where I can list the last record for every fkName, so that I can get the most actual price for every item.

What I have tried so far is a query with

```
SELECT DISTINCT [table1].[Millis], [table2].[Name], [table1].[Price]
FROM [table1]
JOIN [table2] ON [table2].[Id] = [table1].[fkName]
ORDER BY [table2].[Name]
```

But I don't get the correct listing.

Any advice on this? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and portable approach to this greatest-n-per-group problem is to filter with a subquery:

```
select t1.millis, t2.name, t1.price
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.fkName
where t1.millis = (select max(t11.millis) from table1 t11 where t11.fkName = t1.fkName)
order by t1.millis desc
```

Comment: Thanks, can `GROUP BY` somehow also be used?

Comment: @p.j.smith: not really. You need the whole row, so that means filtering, not aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

using Common Table Expression:

```
;with [LastPrice] as (
    select [Millis], [Price], ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by [fkName] order by [Millis] desc) rn
    from [table1] 
)
SELECT DISTINCT [LastPrice].[Millis],[table2].[Name],[LastPrice].[Price]
FROM [LastPrice]
JOIN [table2] ON [table2].[Id] = [LastPrice].[fkName]
WHERE [LastPrice].rn = 1
ORDER BY [table2].[Name]
```